# I'm unable to install PHP5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, php

```
root@areeb-Inspiron-3420:/var/www/html# apt install php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
root@areeb-Inspiron-3420:/var/www/html# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16.04 does not have PHP 5 in the official repositories. Install a 14.04 system, or use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

Comment: Oddly enough, once I got it PHP5+apache set up through that PPA, I was able to `ppa-purge -o ppa:ondrej/php` and I still have php5... *and* I can use Imagemagick and other things the normal Ubuntu PHP5 packages have.

Comment: @NoBugs I'd be curious to see where those PHP 5 packages are coming from; could you please pastebin the output of `apt list --installed | grep php`?

Comment: Ok looks like either they just removed, or just added them: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php5.6+site%3Apackages.ubuntu.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=xenial+php5.6+site:packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: Yes, there were PHP 5 packages in Xenial when it was still in development, but they were removed some time before the release.

Comment: Why would they have removed them?

Comment: Mostly because they didn't want to release (and have to support) both, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1522422

Answer (score 22):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with PHP 7.0. To install it, you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Or rather pick a specific PHP Web SAPI, most probably you need support for Apache2:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php php
```

Or PHP FPM

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm php
```

If you specifically need PHP 5.x, you'll need to use `ppa:ondrej/php` and install, f.e. PHP 5.6 for Apache2:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6 libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

Comment: Sorry but in pure Ubuntu 16.04 LTS `apt-get install php` gives back `Unable to locate package php`. So frustrating!

Comment: @Sliq It must be your local configuration error since `php` package is available in Xenial: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php

Comment: Thanks, I think the packages on Vagrant box are broken or so (as it's the most official boxavailable) :(